# fgets is getting only the last line of my file

Tags: c, fgets, stdio

i'm trying to write a code that inverts the lines of a file, something like this:

Original file:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Output file should be:

```
ccc
bbb
aaa
```

but , actualy the output file is like this:

```
ccc
ccc
ccc
```

i cant understand why. here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char linha[500];
    char *linhas[100];
    int flag = 0;
    FILE *texto,*invertido;
    // populando o vetor
    for(flag =0;flag < 100;flag++)
        linhas[flag] = linha;

    texto = fopen("texto.txt","r");
    if(texto == NULL)
        return 0;
    rewind(texto);
    for(flag = 0;fgets(linhas[flag],500,texto)!=NULL;flag++);

    flag--;
    invertido = fopen("invertido.txt","w");

    if(invertido == NULL)
        return 0;

    for(;flag >= 0;flag--)
        fprintf(invertido,"%d - %s\n",flag,linhas[flag]);

    fclose(invertido);
    fclose(texto);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
linhas[flag] = linha;
```

you make all pointers in `linhas` point to the exact same place. So in the reading loop all lines you read will overwrite what was previously in the single buffer pointer to by `linhas[flag]`.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Use an array of arrays, like in

   ```
   char linhas[100][500];
   ```
2. Allocate each entry in `linhas` dynamically:

   ```
   for(flag =0;flag < 100;flag++)
       linhas[flag] = malloc(500);
   ```